# How does array's rank property relate to its mathematical relative

Tags: arrays, common-lisp, linear-algebra, rank

In Common LISP, arrays have the property `rank` which yields the number of dimensions of the array. However, in linear algebra (where it seems to be borrowed from), `rank` describes the number of non-zero rows in its row echelon matrix. How do these two notions of `rank` relate to one another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays are not matrices; matrices can be *represented* by arrays. You can use a matrix to describe a vector space, in which case the rank of the matrix tells you the dimension of the vector space.

The "rank" of an array in the Common Lisp sense *can not* tell you the dimension of the associated vector space, but it *can* tell you the *maximal* dimension of the associated vector space in some cases. Sometimes this is called the *full rank* of a matrix. The caveat here is that the Lisp "rank" of an array is the full rank of that matrix for square matrices or matrices with fewer rows than columns, but not for matrices with more rows than columns. In that case there are too many row vectors for linear independence, and the number of column vectors would give the full rank.

There is no way to "map" between the rank and the full rank of a matrix, since a matrix can be of any rank which is at most the full rank of the matrix, and there is certainly no way to map between matrix rank and array rank in the Common Lisp sense. Matrix rank gives you a deep property of a matrix, but array rank only gives *part* of the size information for the array, i.e., the number of rows.

Maybe another way to say this is: array rank is only about the container, but matrix rank is about the contents of the container.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes it really clear!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought:   The latter notion of rank is sort of the *dimension* of the space spanned by the NZ rows, whereas in Lisp, Python, etc. it's the *dimension* of an array.

Comment: But is there any way to map between these concepts? Can you say for example that arrays represent row echelon matrices only? And why isn't the rank of a 4x5 matrix 2 then?